# How skip user confirmation with email for omniauth(social authentication)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

My omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb

```
class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController

def facebook
    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])    

    if @user.persisted?
        sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication
        set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
    else
        session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
        redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
end

def google_oauth2
    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env['omniauth.auth'])

    if @user.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Google") if is_navigational_format?
    else
        session["devise.google_oauth2_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
        redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end
```

end
My usermodel is,

```
   def self.from_omniauth(auth)
where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
    user.fullname = auth.info.name
    user.provider = auth.provider
    user.uid = auth.uid
    user.email = auth.info.email
    user.image = auth.info.image
    user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
  end
```

end

I would like to skip confirmation for facebook and google users, where can i put the user.skip_confirmation! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ideal place to add it would be in your `User.from_omniauth` factory method as setting it in the controller would cause an additional UPDATE query.

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
  where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
    user.fullname = auth.info.name
    user.provider = auth.provider
    user.uid = auth.uid
    user.email = auth.info.email
    user.image = auth.info.image
    user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
    user.skip_confirmation! unless user.confirmed?
  end
end
```

`unless user.confirmed?` just ensures that `confirmed_at` is not updated every time the user logs in.